# Show incoming call on a black and locked screen ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc

I'm developing an WebRTC app for android using Ionic framework.

But I'm facing some problems trying to show up when the device receive a call.

When the smarthphone is locked and the screen is off, how can I show the incoming call like whats app does when you call someone.

Or only native apps can does that?

I tried to use this cordova plugin

https://github.com/boltex/cordova-plugin-powermanagement

Using the WAKE_LOCK event, but without success

Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you tried anything else

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper see my edit

Comment: Did your solve it?

Comment: @Stony I solve it using the Socket.io pattern and the WebRTC lib for android. Using this two libs "io.pristine:libjingle" and "io.socket:socket.io-client".

Comment: Thanks, you may put it as answer which may be helpful to others.

Comment: @Stony I will do that, since the answer will be quite long I'm trying to have the proper free time to do it.

Comment: @ErickGallani can you share with us how you fix this issue